# How to handle list/entity operations in flutter?

Tags: rest, flutter, crud

I have the following REST API to connect to:

- `GET` `/notes` - returns a list of {id, name}
- `GET` `/notes/id` - returns full entity by id {id, name, body}
- `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`

I can handle `/notes` or `/notes/id` endpoints separately without a problem, there are plenty examples of that online.

But I have troubles synchronizing them. There should be a proven pattern for handling such situation in flutter, can you recommend one?

Maybe an online sample where people not just read one entity or load the list from database along with all entities data? Need to display the list first, and load full entity data later when user chooses a particular entity based on name.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "synchronizing them"?

Comment: @JoãoSoares sure, I can explain. My global app state would contain a list of entity headers and an entity that is being currently displayed/updated. When I make changes in entity update screen and submit changes, they have to go to both the list (to update entity name) and to the entity itself. That's where I encounter problems. Should I keep entity and list in different providers? Should the entity be in the same provider as the list?